# Windows Form WebBrowser control shows a web page but innerHTML doesn't contain text shown on web page

Tags: c#, html, screen-scraping

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and C# 5.0 to develop a Windows Form application that contains a WebBrowser control.
When I do "webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(loginUrl));" I see a web page in the Windows Form.
If I move my cursor over the WebBrowser window and do "View source" I see the HTML, and
ff I copy and paste the HTML into Notepad, I can the find the text I'm looking for.

But if I do:

```
  var document = webBrowser.Document;
  var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3) document.DomDocument;
  var sHTML = documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

the sHTML does not contain the text I'm looking for.

Why not?  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Charles

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and was able to see the contents of the web page.

I added a button to the form and clicked it after the web page page loaded.

If I tried to access the the document from the webBrowser component in the Load event handler of the form, the document was null, but it did not throw a null pointer exception. It looked like the code ran, but it didn't. Only by adding a try - catch block did I detect the exception.